# Submitting to the appstore: Once an app is reviewed by Apple, does it automatically go live on the app store?

Tags: ios-appstore, app-store-connect

I'm not a developer yet but need a quick answer to this question.
I know when submitting an iPhone App to the App Store, Apple is reviewing the App precisely.

I wonder how this works. Lets say the app is fine and Apple says it's ok, does the app go live on the app store immediately or does the developer get a OK-Message and can "publish" the app later on?

Comment: Have a look at our [faq] to learn what limited scope we have on itunes-connect issues. Basically we consider beta software and parts of the developer programs that require a signed NDA agreement to be off-topic. Your question is general enough and there have been lots of press on developers forgetting to change the "go live" date on an app, that clearly there is a process in place, but no one goes on the record to explain how NDA covered topics work for some odd reason or another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually good you're not a developer since the inner workings of the review queue are generally cloaked under an NDA. Once you join, [Apple has a dedicated site for you to ask questions like this and learn](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/index.html) how the approval and sale process works. I believe it's common knowledge that you can list an "on sale" date when you submit an app for review and then change it later to move it earlier once it's approved, but I wouldn't want to be held to the details of how it works today.